# Cassandra DSE to Cassandra DSC migration

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have three nodes of Cassandra dse on three servers. I need to uninstall dse and install dsc, also I need to migrate the data from the dse cluster to dsc Cassandra cluster **on the same servers**.

What would be the best way to do it? Should I just install dsc and set the data folders in the configuration same as in the dse configuration?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have less amount of data then first export data to CSV from DSE and import data from those CSV to DSC.
2. If you have much data then use sstableloader [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html).

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to do it? Should I just install dsc and set the data folders in the configuration same as in the dse configuration?

No because DSE has some special schema like dse_security etc ...

You can use Apache Spark to migrate quickly your data from DSE to DSC.

Comment: but I need to transfer data from dse (enterprise) to dsc (community) on the same servers...Do you mean to turn on both nodes on the same server (and config different ports, etc`...) and to use spark on the same server? Or turn on both (dsc & dse) whole clusters?

Comment: You can run **temporarily** both DSE and DSC on the same server with **different** ports, then use Spark to migrate. **WARNING: go slowly with the load because the hardware is shared between 2 Cassandra**